# Find the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a^n/n!}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}$$

$a>0, n\in N$

If possible, a solution through the squeeze theorem. Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: How do you define a negative factorial?

Comment: $n\in N$, fixed

Comment: But you said $n \to -\infty$ so $n$ is not fixed.

Comment: Whoops, it was a mistake. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a^k}{k!}-\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^k}{k!}=e-e=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method $1$.

Consider:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}$$

Show it converges for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ by the ratio test. Then consequently we must have your limit going to $0$ by the divergence test for series (if it didn't go to zero then the series would diverge).

Method $2$.

Consider the sequence given by:

$$a_n=\frac{a^n}{n!}$$

Then

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{a}{n+1}a_n$$

And for $n+1>a \implies n>a-1$ we have:

$$a_{n+1}<a_n$$

But if $a>0,n>0$ we have $a_n>0$.

$a_n$ is eventually decreasing, and is positive. Hence the sequence must have a limit.

Call this limit $L$. Because $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n+1)$ and we have $a_{n+1}=a_n\frac{a}{n+1}$ we must have:

$$L=L\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{n+1}=0$$

Comment: Exactly $a_n=\frac{a^n}{n!} \to 0$ because the sum converges by the ratio test (and in fact converges to $e^a$). @FaraadArmwood

Comment: Looking up what those terms are, I can understand your answer, but I believe I am supposed to solve in through the means available to me, and we haven't learned about the divergence test. Is there a simpler way or did I pick an exercise that utilizes a method we've yet to learn?

Comment: @JohnDoe I have edited my answer to include another method.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

We know $$\mathrm{e}^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ x^n }{n!} $$

Has radius of convergence $R=\infty$. Thus, it better converge for $x=a$. It follows then that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ a^n }{n!} = 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

Choose $N\ge 2|a|$, then for $n > N$ we have
$| { |a|^n \over n!} | \le { |a|^N \over N!}{1 \over 2^{n-N}}$, from which 
it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} | { |a|^n \over n!} |  = 0$.

Comment: Why can you choose $N \geq 2 |a| $. it is hard to understand this. can you explain ? thanks

Comment: @ILoveMath: $a$ is a fixed number, and you need to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ such that if $n ge N$ then $| { |a|^n \over n!} | < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$.

Comment: I dont see any $\epsilon $ tho

Comment: @ILoveMath: The OP stated that they wanted to see a proof using the squeeze theorem, so the above shows that since ${1 \over 2^n}$ converges to zero, so does ${a_n \over 2^n}$. The above shows that if $n >N$ then $| { |a|^n \over n!} | \le { |a|^N \over N!}{1 \over 2^{n-N}}$. So, given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N' \ge N$ such that $ { |a|^N \over N!}{1 \over 2^{n-N}} < \epsilon $ for all $n \ge N'$ and you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$A_n=\frac{a^n}{n!}\implies \log(A_n)=n \log(a)-\log(n!)$$ and use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $\log(n!)$. This will give
$$\log(A_n)=n (\log (a)-\log (n)+1)-\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(n\right)+\log (2 \pi
   )\right)-\frac{1}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So, the key term is $-n\log(n)$ which makes $\log(A_n)\to-\infty$ which implies $A_n \to 0$.

When you have problems of limits for expressions containing factorials, Stirling approximation is, most of the time, the key tool to use.